# AppleScript get title of a window

Tags: windows, applescript, title

I try to get the title of an app (and copy it as a var)
Here is my code so far but this is failing

```
tell application "app"
    activate
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    set frontApp to name of first application process whose frontmost is true
end tell

tell application frontApp
    if the (count of windows) is not 0 then
        set window_name to name of front window
    end if
end tell
```

Result :

> error "app got an error: every window doesn’t understand the “count” message." number -1708 from every window

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error message suggests that the frontmost application is not *scriptable*.

The only way to target a non-scriptable application's windows is via the properties of `[application] process` objects from the `System Events` context - *not* via its `application` object (only *scriptable* `application` objects have `windows` elements):

```
tell application "app"
    activate
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    # Get the frontmost app's *process* object.
    set frontAppProcess to first application process whose frontmost is true
end tell

# Tell the *process* to count its windows and return its front window's name.
tell frontAppProcess
    if count of windows > 0 then
       set window_name to name of front window
    end if
end tell
```